# JQuery UI Autocomplete Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I want to add autocompletion in a nickname search bar. I do not understand why it does not work. My code is correct ?

In my file liste.php

```
 global $wpdb;
    $name = $_POST['code_postal'];
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM membres WHERE pseudo LIKE '$name%' ");

    $titles = array();
    foreach($sql as $key=> $value){
        echo $value->pseudo;
    }

    echo json_encode($titles); //encode into JSON format and output
```

In my global.js

```
$('#recherche').autocomplete({
    source: function(name, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'wp-content/themes/ARLIANE/liste.php',
            data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In my index.php

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="term" id="recherche"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Typo in liste.php [...] membErs [...] ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: I guessed you want to access the table "members" but are trying "membres" which would be a spelling mistake

Comment: No it's good "membres". I'm french ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to log ajax errors to console for more informations about the problem , something like this :

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'wp-content/themes/ARLIANE/liste.php',
        data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
        success: function(data) {
            response(data);
        },
       error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
       console.log(xhr.statusText);
       console.log(textStatus);
       console.log(error);
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the URL in your js code by adding a page and to associate the file liste.php as a custom page Type and Than add the page URL  :

```
url: '<?php echo get_permalink(page_id); ?>',
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do a include of liset.php this returns me well a table json.
But when I make my ajax call it returns a Error 500.

I think the problem comes from the jquery call with the autocomplete function.